# Magento 2 : Pass a value to the modal popup from UI Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form, modal-popup, values

I am creating a slider module. I am using the same structure of the customer address form. Add New button will open a modal and show a form. From that, I can upload the image and save it.
[image]
[image]

Now I am facing an issue with transferring the primary key value to the modal popup.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<insertForm ...>
...
<settings>
    ...
    <exports>
        <link name="row_id">${ $.externalProvider }:data.row_id</link>
    </exports>
</settings>
</insertForm>
```